# Adding views to the bottom of a frame layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I'm drawing a deck of cards for a program of mine, and am stacking these cards using a framelayout. When I get rid of a card, I'd like to add another underneath the deck using FrameLayout.addView() or something similar. Any suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

FrameLayout is [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)'s child so ViewGroups addView method family should be fully available.

Consider using ViewGroup.addView(View view, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) ([http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29)).